# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.isRecycled()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-canvas

I get that error with `R.drawable.diamond` that is a `.xml` file. If I replace it with a `.png` file, I don't get any error. So maybe I am using the wrong command.

**R.drawable.diamond.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:height="100dp" android:width="70dp"
    android:viewportHeight="100" android:viewportWidth="100">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF5722"
        android:pathData="M 5,5 95,5 95,95 5,95 z"
        android:strokeAlpha="1"
        android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:strokeLineCap="butt"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round"
        android:strokeWidth="4"/>

    <path
        android:fillColor="#8BC34A"
        android:pathData="m 50,30 l 20,20 -20,20 -20,-20 z"
        android:strokeAlpha="1"
        android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:strokeLineCap="butt"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round"
        android:strokeWidth="4"/>

</vector>
```

**GameView.java**

```
public class GameView extends View {

    private final Bitmap diamond;
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Canvas canvas = new Canvas();

    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        diamond = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.diamond);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(diamond,0,0,null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Vector doesn't have a bitmap associated with it.**
That's the main reason of error

But if still you wanna achieve this you can do like this to get the **Bitmap**

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromVector(Context context, int vectorDrawableRes) {
    Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(vectorDrawableRes);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

And here is an example:

```
Bitmap drawableBitmap = getBitmapFromVector(context, R.drawable.diamond);
```

Comment: Ok thanks it seems to solve the issue. But is it a good practice to draw a vector as a bitmap? Or is it better another way? Consider that in the code I have to change the vector color often.

Comment: To be honest completely up to you... Vector (Shapes) gives you some extra powers on other hand, PNG or any Raster just an IMAGE and you can't really edit it on-air so better if you have option to use Vector always do :D